# Fake Stack Overflow site on http://stackverflow.com/ - illegal?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

stackverflow-dot-com has recently been updated to be a clone of the real Stack Overflow site, and most likely steals information.

Is this website illegally using the Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange logos, and can it be shut down for that?

[image: Picture, for those who don't want to actually go to the site]

Comment: I tried the site (might have been a dumb idea) and it redirected me to the real stack overflow where I was already signed in. So what's the point of those who made it?

Comment: @ABochur the reason that it redirected you to our site, is that they copied all of the source code and pasted it in their website, they may have forgotten to change a few things, but if you scroll down and open a post you can clearly see the link is stackvrflow...

Comment: @Robert: Not sure it's worth editing out a link for the search engines' sake if it's already nofollowed.

Comment: "source code"? Do you mean the HTML (in the dump)?